# correct usage of "not only...but also" in the following sentences

Tags: grammaticality

I'm trying to write 2 sentences with "**not only...but also**", but I don't really no if they are correct or not!

---

1.I don’t like to go to college because **not only** it costs a lot **but they also** might waste my time by teaching unnecessary topics.

2.as a junior or senior web developer, **not only** you can work for companies **but you also** can work as a self-employed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1.I don’t like to go to college because not only does it cost a lot but it might also waste my time by making me learn unnecessary topics.
>
> 2.As a junior or senior web developer, not only you can work for companies but you can also work as self-employed.

I think this is a more natural placement of the word ***also***. In the first sentence it may be confusing if you change the subject, so I made it work with ***IT***, which refers to ***going to college*** or ***higher education*** in general.

Another point is that if a clause begins with ***not only*** (as in sentence 1), you can use the inversion of Auxiliary and Subject, although it is not compulsory, especially in spoken language.

Comment: thanks for your answer
could please do me a favor and write the correct version of my sentences?

Comment: I did! The first sentence would be poor English if you use "they".

Comment: I'm so sorry, now I can see it. thank u so much